# How do I fit a curve to a dataset consisting of multiple curves given as individual datapoints

Tags: r

I was given a dataset consisting of 80 curves which are given as individual points. The curves represent the decline of batteries untill they are no longer useful. The objective is to model a curve which fits this data the best and predict the lifetime of a battery.

[image]

I have tried polynomial regression so far, in what other ways could I model a curve?

Answer (score 2):

If you have the lifetime of multiple batteries, you can treat that as time-to-event - that is, you have the time it takes for a battery to run dead. In such case, you can perform a survival analysis.

If you have only the time-to-event, you can draw a Kaplan-Meier survival curve. If you have other variables that can explain why some batteries last longer than others, you can try a Cox regression to evaluate the effect of those variables in the lifetime of batteries in your dataset.

[Edit] Now looking at your plot, it seems that you are trying to model an "average" curve learning from all the 80 curves. In that case, a possible approach would be to find the parameters of each individual curve (eg. modeling each one of them individually) and then inferring the true parameters of the population of curves, eg. by Bayesian inference. As result of this process you would get the most likely (maximum likelihood) parameters for a general curve that would represent what you know about the lifetime of your batteries.